# Finding an explicit curve when torsion and curvature are equivalent

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I know solving the Frenet-Serret equations for a given curvature and torsion is possible, but only analytically possible under special cases like plane curves. Is there something I can exploit to calculate a unit-speed curve where, for instance, $\kappa(s)=\tau(s)=\sqrt{2}/(1+s^2)$?

Comment: See pages 32-33, 44-45 in Millman and Parker, Elements of Differential Geometry, Lancret's theorem.

Answer (score 3):

See my answer on StackExchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28925/explicit-formula-for-space-curves/28931#28931